# Disable JFrame minimize button

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jdialog, jwindow

I am developing a tool for my laptop. I want to disable minimize button in the JFrame. I have already disabled maximize and close button.

Here is the code to disable maximize and close button:

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame();  
frame.setResizable(false); //Disable the Resize Button  
// Disable the Close button
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
```

Please, tell me how to disable minimize button.

Comment: *"Please, tell me how to disable minimize button."*  Please, don't do that.

Comment: What is the actual goal of the GUI here?  Is it a kiosk?

Comment: display the battery charge info to the user in laptop.

Comment: Thanks for explaining.  How are you finding that value in Java?

Answer (score 10):

Generally, you can't, what you can do is use a `JDialog` instead of `JFrame`

Answer (score 10):

As @MadProgrammer said (+1 to him), this is definitely not a good idea you'd rather want to

- use a `JDialog` and call `setDefaultCloseOperation(JDialog.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);` to make sure it cannot be closed.
- You could also use a `JWindow` (+1 to @M. M.) or call `setUndecorated(true);` on your `JFrame` instance.

Alternatively you may want to add your own `WindowAdapater` to make the `JFrame` un-minimizable etc by overriding `windowIconified(..)` and calling `setState(JFrame.NORMAL);` from within the method:

```
//necessary imports
import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Test {

    /**
     * Default constructor for Test.class
     */
    public Test() {
        initComponents();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        /**
         * Create GUI and components on Event-Dispatch-Thread
         */
        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Test test = new Test();
            }
        });
    }
    private final JFrame frame = new JFrame();

    /**
     * Initialize GUI and components (including ActionListeners etc)
     */
    private void initComponents() {
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.addWindowListener(getWindowAdapter());

        //pack frame (size JFrame to match preferred sizes of added components and set visible
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private WindowAdapter getWindowAdapter() {
        return new WindowAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent we) {//overrode to show message
                super.windowClosing(we);

                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "Cant Exit");
            }

            @Override
            public void windowIconified(WindowEvent we) {
                frame.setState(JFrame.NORMAL);
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "Cant Minimize");
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: On Mac windowIconified is working in strangeway. Jframe is getting minimized for a second and then getting back on screen and then showing the messageDialog.

Answer (score 8):

If you don't want to allow any user action use `JWindow`.

Comment: See also the [Full-Screen Exclusive Mode API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/fullscreen/index.html).  If making an app. that paints every pixel on-screen, it can be very handy.

Answer (score 6):

You may try to change your JFrame type to UTILITY. Then you will not see both minimize btn and maximize btn in your program.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend you to use  `jframe.setUndecorated(true)`  as you are not using any of the window events and do not want the application to be resized. Use the  [MotionPanel](http://d3ep4k.blogspot.in/2013/07/moving-undecorated-window-by-clicking.html) that I've made, if you would like to move the panel.

Comment: People can still minimize the JFrame by clicking on the icon in the windows task bar...

Comment: In that case you minimize to system tray